# sum of n Fisher information matrix divided by n

Tags: probability, convergence, fisher-information

Suppose $X_i$'s are independent, where $i=1,2,...,n$. The density function of $X_i$ is $f_{\theta_i}(x)$. Let Fisher information of $X=(X_1, ...,X_n)$ be $I_X$. Then $$I_X = \sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{X_i},$$
where $I_{X_i}$ is the Fisher information of distribution $f_{\theta_i}(x)$.

My question does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{I_{X}}{n}$ exists? If so, denote the limit as $I_{\infty}$. Does $\frac{I_{X}}{n}$ converge to $I_{\infty}$ in probability?

Comment: I suppose you mean $I_X/n$

Comment: You need to specify more about $\theta_i$. For example, suppose the $f_{\theta_i}$ density is $N(0,\theta_i^{-1})$, so the information $I_{X_i}$ is $\theta_i$.  Whether the limit exists just depends on how the $\theta_i$ are chosen, and there isn't any randomness to make convergence in probability a separate question.

Comment: @ThomasLumley I see. Thank you. So whether the limit exists depends, and sometimes we have to assume it exists.

Comment: Yes.  You would typically either assume that $\theta_i$ were sampled from some random process with (eg) finite moments, or treat them as fixed, but make assumptions about infinite sums that are basically the same as assuming finite moments.